# Why does this Bean created with new also get field injected?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Here is some code which I am curious to know how it works: it is a `@Bean` method that returns an object instantiated with `new`. Yet at the same time it manages to get field injected as there is a "stereotype" of the class which is `@ConfigurationProperties` annotated:

The producer is [ConfigClientAutoConfiguration.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/main/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/client/ConfigClientAutoConfiguration.java):

The method is

```
@Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public ConfigClientProperties configClientProperties(Environment environment, ApplicationContext context) {
        if (context.getParent() != null && BeanFactoryUtils.beanNamesForTypeIncludingAncestors(context.getParent(),
                ConfigClientProperties.class).length > 0) {
            return BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfTypeIncludingAncestors(context.getParent(), ConfigClientProperties.class);
        }
// this looks like a standard constructor call
// why would Spring "know" to inject fields
        ConfigClientProperties client = new ConfigClientProperties(environment);
        return client;
    }
```

In applications we are told that objects created with `new` always bypass field injection.

Here is the “stereotype” of that class [ConfigClientProperties.java](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/blob/main/spring-cloud-config-client/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/config/client/ConfigClientProperties.java) - due to the way the object is created I would think that it would bypass field injection, yet at runtime the fields are all correctly populated from properties.

In this code (spring-cloud-config-client) this is a wrapper object for a bunch of `spring.cloud.config*` properties needed to make HTTP calls.

TL;DR in Spring factories how does the context know to take an object, match it with a "stereotype" and do field injection instead of leaving the object uninjected?

Answer (score 0):

The properties of the `ConfigClientProperties` bean are populated by Spring Boot because the class is annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`. You can read more about how this works in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties).

Spring Boot implements this using a [Spring Framework `BeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp). After all beans have been added to the application context (for example, from the `@Bean` methods in `ConfigClientAutoConfiguration`), a `BeanPostProcessor` in Spring Boot inspects beans to see if they are annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` and populates properties of any such annotated beans from the environment.